# Existence of a bounded right inverse to a linear closed surjective operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A:D_A \subseteq H \to K$ a linear closed surjctive operator between two Hilbert spaces $H$ and $K$.

One would expect that in such a situation there must exist a bounded right inverse of $A$, namely an operator $R:K \to H$ such that $AR=Id_K$. In fact this is certainly true if $A$ is bijective but the proof doesn't seem to go through with the hypothesis of surjectivity.

Any ideas what is going on in this situation ?

EDIT: Although the answers cover my original question, i think it is quite natural at this point to ask wether this is true if $H$ and $K$ are more generally Banach space instead of Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Does something go wrong if you simply quotient out the kernel? Then the induced operator is bijective.

Comment: But then how do you know that the quotient operator is still closed?

Comment: Ok now I see even if the operator is not bounded the kernel is closed, right?

Comment: The kernel is closed but I don't think it has to be complemented in $D_A$. I smell a counterexample (at least if you want $R$ to be bounded) but I don't have time to think about it now ...

Comment: Maybe differentiation on $L^2(0,\infty)$ would work as a counterexample? The right inverse would essentially have to be the antiderivative and unboundedness of the domain should show that it is unbounded. I don't have time to check the details now, sorry.

Comment: Differentiation on $L^2(0,\infty)$ is not surjective.

Comment: If the quotient map $q:X \to X/Y$ has a right inverse $j:X/Y \to X$ then $jq:X \to X$ is a projection whose kernel is $Y$. Such a $j$ does not exist if $Y$ is uncomplemented in $X$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune that depends on what you mean by "uncomplemented". The image of this projection need not be a closed subspace, but every subspace of a pre-Hilbert space has an unclosed algebraic complement.

Comment: @Nik Weaver Yes, I am only dealing with closed subspaces in general Banach spaces. In my situation $jq(X)$ is closed since coincides with the kernel of $I-jq$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still true in the unbounded case, and you can see this using polar decomposition. Write $A = BU$ where $B$ is some positive unbounded operator on $K$ and $U$ is the orthogonal projection from $H$ onto a closed subspace $H_0$ followed by some isometry from $H_0$ onto $K$. We can take $B$ to be a multiplication operator, $B = M_f$, on $K = L^2(X)$, and then the fact that $BU$ is surjective implies that $f$ must be bounded away from zero. So $1/f$ is a bounded function and thus $B^{-1} = M_{1/f}$ is a bounded operator. Finally, $U^*B^{-1}$ is the desired bounded right inverse.

Comment: You are assuming H is a Hilbert space. The notation may suggest it, but this was never specified explicitly.

Comment: Yes, I thought it was obvious from the notation that we're talking about Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mentioned that the spaces are assumed to be Hilbert.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that one can prove the existence of a right inverse without using the polar composition: If we endow $D(A)$ with the graph norm, $A$ becomes a continuous linear surjection between Hilbert spaces and thus has a continuous linear right inverse into $D(A)$ which is also continuous as an operator with values in $H$.

This applies also to real Hilbert spaces and in some situations even to Banach spaces, if the range $K$ is projective, e.g., $\ell^1$.